# Finding independent predictors with multiple logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, predictor

I am conducting a study in order to find independent predictors of a binary outcome variable (A=110, B=51). The main goal of this work is to verify if any of 14 variables are independent predictors when adjusted to 3 variables that I already now are independent predictors.

Considering the one in ten rule I am able to use only 5 predictors in the multiple logistic regression model. So is it possible to do several multiple models with the same 3 variables and to enter 2 other variables at a time to get these 2 adjusted for the former?

I have been trying to find studies using this approach but I couldn't find any so far (specially from medical literature which is my area of research). If you know any paper describing this approach could you share it with me please?

Comment: When you say "independent predictors", do you mean independently predict the outcome with just your three key variables or independently predict the outcome with all other variables in the model? This is a key difference in interpretation and will determine how to proceed. For example, biological age and chronological age may each predict an outcome, but neither "independently" predicts it in a model with both included.

Comment: Probably, the misunderstanding here has to do with the term "independent predictor" which is often used in medical literature for a variable for which a significant association was found, even after controlling for covariates (in a multiple logistic regression model for example). The main goal of my work is testing if 14 variables (most of which are binary and correspond to the absence or presence of a symptom) are independent predictors of the outcome variable - so the question I am trying to answer is: Does the presence of any of these symptoms independently predicts an A or B outcome?

Comment: Right, but the question is independently of what? Independently of the 13 other variables, or independently of the 3 you have already decided to include?

Comment: Sorry.. Independently of the 3 that I have already decided to include

Comment: Oh, then you only need to include one focal predictor at a time in 14 logistic regressions that each include only your 3 included predictors and one focal predictor. Note that this analysis will not help you figure out if any of the 14 are redundant or not.

Comment: Ok, I also think that makes sense but I have never seen a paper describing this approach. Do you know any study which uses this method?